# Database access: one master database object or have objects call queries themselves?

Tags: sql, database, theory

For a hobby project I am building an application to keep track of my money. Register everything that comes in and goes out. I am using sqlite as a database backend. 
I have two data access models in mind.

- Creating one master object as a sort of database connector, which contains methods which execute the queries and provide the required sets of data as a list of objects
- Have objects who need data execute the queries themselves

Which one of these is 'the best' and why? Or are there different, better models out there?

Comment: I would initially take the simplest route, embed SQL wherever you need it.  If a good reason came up to move it to one file, that sounds like a pretty straightforward refactoring.

Comment: I use a combination. One "master" connection object for but actual SQL code is contained in the separate models where it's needed.

Comment: "best" is in the eye of the beholder - please provide a concrete question, not an invitation to a discussion...

Answer (score 1):

The latter option is better. In the first option, you would end up having to touch your universal data access object for just about any update to the code that wasn't purely a change in display logic. If you have different data access objects, then you will have much more testable, maintainable code.

I suggest you read up a bit on the model-view-controller paradigm. The wikipedia article on it is a good start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller.

Also, you didn't say which language/platform you were coding in, but most platforms have numerous options for auto-generating a starting point your data access classes from your database. You may find something like that useful.

Answer (score 0):

Much of a muchness really, the thing to avoid is having the "same" sql sprinkled all over your code base.

The key point is. You've just added a new column to Table1. When you do Find In Files "Table1", how many hits are you going to get and where.

If you use one class and there's a lot of db operations, it's going to get very messy very quickly, but if you have one interface (say IModel) with one implementation, you can swap backends very easily.

So how many db operations, and how likely is it you will move away from SqlLite.